# Решение СЛАУ с помощью библиотеки Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen

Я хочу воспользоваться методами библиотеки Eigen для решения СЛАУ.
Я взяла пример из файла документации и проект не компилируется.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
   Matrix3f A;
   Vector3f b;
   A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
   b << 3, 3, 4;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
   Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
   cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
}
```

Ошибка при компиляции:
`Ошибка C1001   Внутренняя ошибка в файле компилятора.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\distr\eigen\eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h  205`

я запускаю консольное приложение с архитектурой x64 на Visual studio 2015 и 2017

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Попробуйте переустановить компилятор](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993745/5767249). Приведённый код не содержит ошибок.

Comment: @maestro, переустановка не помогла